# Link Unexpectedly Changing Color From Black To Blue On Tablet Device

Tags: html, css, ios

**Background**

I have an HTML link, a button, centered on a page, that displays unexpectedly on tablet devices, specifically iPad.

On desktop, the link displays as a black rounded button, however, on tablet, the link displays as a blue rounded button.

---

**Question**

Why is the link turning blue on tablet when there is no code that references blue? What needs to be corrected in the HTML and CSS code below to ensure links on both desktop and tablet display consistently as black?

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttonContinue">
    <a href="#">Continue</a>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
div.buttonContinue a:link, div.buttonContinue a:visited, div.buttonContinue a:hover, div.buttonContinue a:active {
    display: block !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-color: #CCCCCC !important;
    border-width: 1px !important;
    border-radius: 100px !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: #333333 !important;
}

div.buttonContinue a:hover {
    background: #F2F2F2 !important;
}
```

---

**Image**

[image]

Comment: By default all links are blue. You need to change default link color first: just add ```div.buttonContinue a {color: #yourColor}```

Comment: Apparently, It's working fine for me  :(

Comment: Thanks for trying and the suggestion, unfortunately the links remain blue on iPad. Either some other code on the site is influencing the links specifically on the tablet, or possibly iOS is recoloring the links similar as to what it does with telephone numbers.